# What is the NuGet API to help select a given Nuget package target framework that matches the best the given project target framework?

Tags: c#, nuget

Given a project target framework (say net472) and a nuget package with a bunch of supported target frameworks, what NuGet API can we use to match the Nuget target framework to the project target framework?

E.g. `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource` has 5 target frameworks in its package:

- net45
- net46
- netstandard1.1
- netstandard1.3
- portable-net45+win8+wpa81

I want the same NuGet Api that is used by Nuget itself when it decides to match any of these frameworks to net472 (I supposed it would be net46).

It is very hard to find any documentation due to huge amount of false positives in the search.

**EDIT 1**

I figured out it is the `NuGet.Frameworks` package. Looking for the right API now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have at the end of the day:

```
public class FrameworkFromLibFolderPath : IFrameworkSpecific
{
    public FrameworkFromLibFolderPath(string libFolderPath)
    {
        LibFolderPath = libFolderPath;
        TargetFramework = NuGetFramework.ParseFolder(Path.GetFileName(libFolderPath));
    }

    public readonly string LibFolderPath;

    public NuGetFramework TargetFramework { get; }
}
```

And

```
var packageFrameworks = Directory
    .EnumerateDirectories(baseLibFolderPath)
    .Select(libFolderPath => new FrameworkFromLibFolderPath(libFolderPath))
    .ToList();
var path = packageFrameworks.Count > 0 ? packageFrameworks.GetNearest(framework).LibFolderPath : baseLibFolderPath;
```